# what does " on top of " mean here?

Tags: computing

> A desktop environment is a graphical user interface on top of the
>   operating system. GNOME, KDE, Xfce, Fluxbox are some examples of the
>   desktop environment.

I can not understand the meaning of *"on top of"* in this sentence. Sorry for poor English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that the graphical user interface does not itself interact with the hardware. It uses the services that the operating system offers. Likewise, the user interacts with the graphical user interface, not with the operating system. You could draw a picture with the user on top, beneath that the GUI, then the OS, and the hardware at the bottom. Each layer uses the layer underneath.

Answer (score 2):

Computing systems are often described in terms of *layers*. A *layer* may provide a simplified or easier to use interface. The sentence is explaining that a *desktop environment* is such a thing over the operating system.